# Google Drive API IOS Permissions of GTLRDriveService

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, authentication, google-drive-api

I am playing around with the google drive API and trying to build a simple app that uploads a picture to my google drive. The app is supposed to upload a picture once the user is signed in, however it gives an error of

> "2017-09-14 00:55:20.342237-0400 driveTest[6705:1647551] An error
>   occurred: Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403
>   "Insufficient Permission"
>   UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x1c4251d30:
>   {message:"Insufficient Permission" errors:[1] code:403},
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Insufficient Permission}"

I have tried to pass it the service which is of type GTLRDriveService to the initSetup() function of  the userSetUp class, but to no avail. Could someone please point me to the right track as to why my permissions are not working even though I have logged on correctly, and the part where I am passing in the GTLRDriveService is in the code that runs after a sucessful login.

I instantiate a userSetUp object and I 
let setUpUser = userSetUp()
setUpUser.initSetup(service)

I have userSetUp written in objective c as such and it is bridged correctly as I am able to instantiate it in my viewcontroller file which is written in swift.

UserSetUp:::::::

```
#import "userSetUp.h"
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
@import GoogleAPIClientForREST;


@implementation userSetUp
- (void) initSetup:(GTLRDriveService *) driveService {


    printf("heloooooaiosuoiadoidauoalo");
    //GTLRDriveService *driveService = [GTLRDriveService new];
    //NSData *fileData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:@"files/apple.jpg"];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"apple" ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    GTLRDrive_File *metadata = [GTLRDrive_File object];
    metadata.name = @"apple.jpg";
    //metadata.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.document";

    GTLRUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLRUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileData
                                                                                   MIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];
    uploadParameters.shouldUploadWithSingleRequest = TRUE;
    GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate queryWithObject:metadata
                                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
    query.fields = @"id";
    [driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                         GTLRDrive_File *file,
                                                         NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            //NSLog(@"File ID %@", file.identifier);
            printf("it worked");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    }];



printf("upload complete!");


}
@end
```

And Viewcontroller. swift
     import GoogleAPIClientForREST
    import GoogleSignIn
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate     {


// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials by
// resetting the iOS simulator or uninstall the app.
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeDriveReadonly]

let service = GTLRDriveService()
let signInButton = GIDSignInButton()
let output = UITextView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure Google Sign-in.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    signInButton.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width/2 - signInButton.frame.width , y:  view.frame.height/2, width: signInButton.frame.width, height: signInButton.frame.height)
    // Add the sign-in button.
    view.addSubview(signInButton)

    // Add a UITextView to display output.
    output.frame = view.bounds
    output.isEditable = false
    output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
    output.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    output.isHidden = true
    view.addSubview(output);
    //let itsASetup()
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        showAlert(title: "Authentication Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        self.service.authorizer = nil
    } else {
        self.signInButton.isHidden = true
        self.output.isHidden = false
        self.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()

        listFiles()
    }
}

// List up to 10 files in Drive
func listFiles() {
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
    query.pageSize = 10
    service.executeQuery(query,
                         delegate: self,
                         didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
    )

}

// Process the response and display output
@objc func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
                             finishedWithObject result : GTLRDrive_FileList,
                             error : NSError?) {

    if let error = error {
        showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    var text = "";
    if let files = result.files, !files.isEmpty {
        text += "Files:\n"
        for file in files {
            text += "\(file.name!) (\(file.identifier!))\n"
        }
    } else {
        text += "No files found."
    }
    output.text = text
    let setUpUser = userSetUp()
    setUpUser.initSetup(service)
}


// Helper for showing an alert
func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
    )
    let ok = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
        handler: nil
    )
    alert.addAction(ok)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to Change your scope like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate
{
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials by

    private let scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

    ...
}
```